# R: create dummy variables based on a categorical variable *of lists*

Tags: r, list, dummy-variable, tidyverse

I have a data frame with a categorical variable holding *lists* of strings, with variable length (it is important because otherwise this question would be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048638/automatically-expanding-an-r-factor-into-a-collection-of-1-0-indicator-variables) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384506/create-new-dummy-variable-columns-from-categorical-variable)), e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
df$y <- list("A", c("A", "B"), "C", c("B", "D", "C"), "E")
df
```

> ```
>   x       y
> 1 1       A
> 2 2    A, B
> 3 3       C
> 4 4 B, D, C
> 5 5       E
> ```

And the desired form is a dummy variable for each unique string seen anywhere in `df$y`, i.e.:

```
data.frame(x = 1:5, A = c(1,1,0,0,0), B = c(0,1,0,1,0), C = c(0,0,1,1,0), D = c(0,0,0,1,0), E = c(0,0,0,0,1))
```

> ```
>   x A B C D E
> 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
> 2 2 1 1 0 0 0
> 3 3 0 0 1 0 0
> 4 4 0 1 1 1 0
> 5 5 0 0 0 0 1
> ```

This naive approach works:

```
> uniqueStrings <- unique(unlist(df$y))
> n <- ncol(df)
> for (i in 1:length(uniqueStrings)) {
+   df[,  n + i] <- sapply(df$y, function(x) ifelse(uniqueStrings[i] %in% x, 1, 0))
+   colnames(df)[n + i] <- uniqueStrings[i]
+ }
```

However it is very ugly, lazy and slow with big data frames.

Any suggestions? Something fancy from the `tidyverse`?

---

UPDATE: I got 3 different approaches below. I tested them using `system.time` on my (Windows 7, 32GB RAM) laptop on a *real* dataset, comprising of 1M rows, each row containing a list of length 1 to 4 strings (out of ~350 unique string values), overall 200MB on disk. So the expected result is a data frame with dimensions 1M x 350. The `tidyverse` (@Sotos) and `base` (@joel.wilson) approaches took so long I had to restart R. The `qdapTools` (@akrun) approach however worked fantastic:

```
> system.time(res1 <- mtabulate(varsLists))
   user  system elapsed 
  47.05   10.27  116.82
```

So this is the approach I'll mark accepted.

Comment: or `data.frame(x = df$x, t(sapply(df$y, function(l){table(factor(l, levels = LETTERS[1:5]))})))`

Comment: @alistaire maybe `levels = unique(unlist(df$y))` instead of `LETTERS[1:5]` ?

Comment: @Sotos I had that, but figured this is less computation. The best route is to store that as a separate variable, but that would require a second line...

Comment: @alistaire True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df[1], mtabulate(df$y))
#  x A B C D E
#1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#2 2 1 1 0 0 0
#3 3 0 0 1 0 0
#4 4 0 1 1 1 0
#5 5 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: That's impressive and super fast (a few seconds for a ~1M rows with ~350 unique values on my PC). Do you have an answer not requiring a whole new package? Thanks.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni  Looks like somebody else answered it without a package

Comment: @GioraSimchoni too; I guess a base alternative is `table(rep(df$x, lengths(df$y)), unlist(df$y))`?

Comment: Doesn't work with `df$x = rep(1,5)` or `df$x = c(1,1,2,2,3)`. It shouldn't matter what `df$x` is.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni  I am not sure what you meant by doesn't work?  It does give an output where the first column is just 1 (for `df$x = rep(1,5)`)

Comment: Sorry @akrun, I was referring to alexis_laz comment.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni : (hadn't notice the comment) I misunderstood what you wanted -- in that case, simply use `table(rep(seq_along(df$y), lengths(df$y)), unlist(df$y))` and `cbind` `df$x` as in akrun's answer. (@akrun sorry for the unnecessary notification)

Answer (score 7):

Another idea,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 unnest(y) %>% 
 mutate(new = 1) %>% 
 spread(y, new, fill = 0) 

#  x A B C D E
#1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#2 2 1 1 0 0 0
#3 3 0 0 1 0 0
#4 4 0 1 1 1 0
#5 5 0 0 0 0 1
```

Further to the cases you mentioned in comments, we can use `dcast` from `reshape2` as it is more flexible than `spread`,

```
df2 <- df %>% 
        unnest(y) %>% 
        group_by(x) %>% 
        filter(!duplicated(y)) %>% 
        ungroup()

reshape2::dcast(df2, x ~ y, value.var = 'y', length)

#  x A B C D E
#1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#2 2 1 1 0 0 0
#3 3 0 0 1 0 0
#4 4 0 1 1 1 0
#5 5 0 0 0 0 1

#or with df$x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)

#  x A B C D E
#1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#2 2 0 1 1 1 0
#3 3 0 0 0 0 1

#or with df$x <- rep(1,5)

#  x A B C D E
#1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: thanks, see what happens when df$x = rep(1, 5). "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 7)"

Comment: What would your expected result be in such case? something like `df %>% unnest(y) %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(new = 1:n()) %>% spread(y, x, fill = 0)`?

Comment: The same result keeping the original x column. This, on the original `df` gives "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2)".

Comment: It works on the `df$x = rep(1, 5)` case. On the original `df$x = 1:5` case it gives "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2)".

Comment: Try `mutate(new = 1:n())` before `group_by()`

Comment: It doesn't work with `df$x = 1:5`, neither with `df$x = c(1,1,2,2,3)`. It shouldn't matter what `df$x` is.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni can you check now?

Answer (score 2):

this involves no external packages,

```
# thanks to Sotos for suggesting to use `unique(unlist(df$y))` instead of `LETTERS[1!:5]`
sapply(unique(unlist(df$y)), function(j) as.numeric(grepl(j, df$y)))
#     A B C D E
#[1,] 1 0 0 0 0
#[2,] 1 1 0 0 0
#[3,] 0 0 1 0 0
#[4,] 0 1 1 1 0
#[5,] 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: the `LETTERS` part is bad. You can do `unique(unlist(df$y))` instead

Comment: Doesn't work with `df$x = rep(1,5)` or `df$x = c(1,1,2,2,3)`. It shouldn't matter what `df$x` is.

Comment: @joel.wilson works great, I'll make some benchmarks to see how it compares with other "fancier" solutions, thanks.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni how does it perform?