# Using dplyr to gather dummy variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that consists of 5 dummy variables that looks like this....

```
> head(type)
  convertible coupe hatchback sedan wagon
1           0     0         0     1     0
2           0     1         0     0     0
3           1     0         0     0     0
4           1     0         0     0     0
5           1     0         0     0     0
6           1     0         0     0     0
```

If I were to use dplyr code, how can I create a new variable that is called "TypeOfCar" with all of the dummy variables collapsed into it? Thanks!

Edit: Sorry for the ambiguity. Using the information above, I was wondering if there was a way in dplyr to gather up the current set of dummy variables to make ONE variable called TypeOfCar. Example below (respective to the ID's above 1-6)

```
    TypeOfCar
1     sedan
2     coupe
3     convertible
4     convertible
5     convertible
6     convertible
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output as it is not clear

Comment: Try `type$TypeOfCar <- names(type)[max.col(type)]`.  You don't need dplyr, there's no grouping.

Comment: Wow that worked great, thanks!

Comment: Is there also an example, when you want exact the same.. but without for example the column "sedan"?  (so how can we exclude variables to gather?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest creation of factor variable from dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670314/simplest-creation-of-factor-variable-from-dummies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the 'tidyverse' library - specificially 'tidyr' and 'dplyr'. The following code produces the output you are after.

```
library(tidyverse)
type %>% gather(TypeOfCar, Count) %>% filter(Count >= 1) %>% select(TypeOfCar)
```

Output:

```
   TypeOfCar
    <chr>
1 convertible
2 convertible
3 convertible
4 convertible
5       coupe
6       sedan
```

Hopefully this solves your problem, let me know if any changes are needed! Thanks.

Comment: If this helped to answer your question it would be greatly appreciated if you could mark the question as answered. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hey George, how would I be able to put it back into the dataset in order? It seems when I try to cbind back to the original dataframe, the data is scattered.

Comment: Hi :) This does that: library(tidyverse)
D %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(D)) %>% gather(TypeOfCar, Count, -ID) %>% filter(Count >= 1) %>% arrange(ID) %>% select(TypeOfCar)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R`

```
data.frame(TypeOfCar = names(type)[as.matrix(type)%*%seq_along(type)], 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#    TypeOfCar
#1       sedan
#2       coupe
#3 convertible
#4 convertible
#5 convertible
#6 convertible
```

Comment: Not selected but I would choose this over the selected answer given that it retains the original row order. However, dplyr does read easier..