# Using dplyr to gather specific dummy variables

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is the extension of ([Using dplyr to gather dummy variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036652/using-dplyr-to-gather-dummy-variables)) .

**The question:** How can I gather **only a few columns**, instead of the whole dataset? So in this example, I want to gather all the columns, but except "sedan". My real data set has 250 columns, so therefore it will be great if I can **include/exclude the columns by name**.

**Data set**

```
head(type)
x    convertible coupe hatchback sedan wagon
1           0     0         0     1     0
2           0     1         0     0     0
3           1     0         0     0     0
4           1     0         0     0     0
5           1     0         0     0     0
6           1     0         0     0     0
```

**Output**

```
TypeOfCar
1     x
2     coupe 
3     convertible
4     convertible
5     convertible
6     convertible
```

Comment: subset before gather?

Comment: Is a possibility, but it is not desired, since it will cost more memory again :-). There should be a way to do this on a Tidy way, right?

Comment: then maybe you can try the value argument in gather?

Comment: I tried: 
test <- df %>% gather(new_column, Count, 2:4)
But with wrong results...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i'm understanding you, but you can do what you want:

```
df %>% select(-sedan) %>%  gather(Key, Value)
```

And if you have to much variables you can use:

```
select(-contains(""))
select(-start_wi(""))
select(-ends_with(""))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! But when I run it, in the example above.. then the result is slightly different (data frame with 2 columns). I tried to rewrite your code in the example above, but that didn't gave the desired result (since the rows were shuffled). 
what i tried: xj <- dat %>% select(-sedan) %>%  gather(Key, Value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-sedan` in `gather`:

```
dat %>% gather(TypeOfCar, Count, -sedan) %>% filter(Count >= 1) %>% select(TypeOfCar)
#      TypeOfCar
# 1 convertible
# 2 convertible
# 3 convertible
# 4 convertible
# 5       coupe
```

Data:

```
tt <- "convertible coupe hatchback sedan wagon
1           0     0         0     1     0
2           0     1         0     0     0
3           1     0         0     0     0
4           1     0         0     0     0
5           1     0         0     0     0
6           1     0         0     0     0"

dat <- read.table(text = tt, header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use it to select for example multiple columns (let's say only gathering for (convertible,coupe and hatchback)? (so selecting instead of removing 1 variable)

Comment: `gather(TypeOfCar, Count, convertible,coupe,hatchback)` works for you?

Comment: You could use this sintax in order to get multiple consecutive columns `start_column:end_column` or use `contains("X")` in order to match a string

Comment: I totally misused the function. Thanks for the clarity, really helped me out!

Comment: I see, after testing, that only the first name column name is showed. Should I transform my data in a specific format? It is now numeric.

Comment: remove the `%>% filter(Count >= 1) %>% select(TypeOfCar)` part, that was just to get a shorter example.

Comment: still same error: I use now: 
test <- df %>% gather(df, Count, 4:27)  #need to use column 4 until 27

Comment: You don't need to rewrite `df` inside the call if you use the `%>%`, instead write a variable name like `TypeOfCar` this would be the key to the `gather` function

Comment: test <- df %>% gather(key, Count, 4:27)

Result in two new columns (key, which is now representing all the type of cars, but not on the good rows, and Count, which is binary (33051 zeros, and 1437 ones). But the gathering part is still going wrong (not the column names are represented where an 1 occurred)

Comment: I see the problem, I think. You should probably use `%>% select(key, count)` after the `gather`

Comment: Thanks, but that will lead to a data frame with much more rows (containing key and Count (I assume that Count is with capital c?). Code used: 

test <- df %>% gather(key, Count, 4:27) %>% select(key,Count)

Comment: Thanks! But the answer in your example is not correct, right? It should be: 
1 =  x 
2 = coupe
3 = convertible 
4 = convertible 
5 = convertible 
6 = convertible

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a combination of @RLave and @Carlos Vecina

```
right_columns <- all_data %>% select(starts_with("hour"))

all_data$all_hour <-data.frame(new_column = names(right_columns )[as.matrix(right_columns )%*%seq_along(right_columns )],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```