# How to create a new column based on different columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a the following `df`

| id | tiger | donkey | turtle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

So that 1 equals True and 0 equals False.

And I want to create the following `df`

| id | animal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tiger |
| 2 | donkey |
| 3 | turtle |

How would I do this using `dplyr`? I first thought that I could use `pivot_long()` but I should not have more rows after the operation.

Comment: You can find responses here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130366/reconstruct-a-categorical-variable-from-dummies-in-r

Comment: More responses here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036652/using-dplyr-to-gather-dummy-variables. and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333401/convert-various-dummy-logical-variables-into-a-single-categorical-variable-facto

Comment: @RuamPimentel good finds. Most of those are either (a) `melt` (ala the reshape suggestion in my answer) or (b) using the outdated `tidyr::gather`. I suspect there are other dupes of this, as is it a common-enough question. I'm happy closing it as a dupe if there's a better one out there that includes relatively recent `tidyr` solutions (as `dplyr`-alone is not a great method for this).

Comment: Uhum. I agree with you @r2evans that they are showing some outdated options. I would suggest updating the answer on those posts instead of starting a new one here because they have already nice discussions there. But I’m not sure what is the best take. Given you have way more experience than me on SO, I leave to you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
pivot_longer(dat, -id, names_to = "animal") %>%
  filter(value > 0)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id animal value
#   <int> <chr>  <int>
# 1     1 tiger      1
# 2     2 donkey     1
# 3     3 turtle     1
```

### base plus reshape2

```r
subset(
  reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = "id", variable.name = "animal"),
  value > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility with **dplyr** :

```
id = c(1,2,3)
tiger = c( 1,0,0)
donkey = c(0,1,0)
turtle = c(0,0,1)

original_df = data.frame(id,tiger,donkey,turtle)

library(dplyr)

original_df %>% mutate(animal = case_when(tiger==1~"tiger", donkey==1~"donkey", 
turtle==1~"turtle")) %>% select(id,animal)
```